# ZeroRPC and IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, rpc, zeromq

I would really like to use the excellent [zerorpc](https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python) for my project that uses IronPython, but it doesn't seem to be supported.

I have tried downloading the zip of the source for `zerorpc` and running

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" setup.py install
```

but I see this along the way:

```
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
```

This does not contradict the answer: [Fast and scalable RPC between C# and CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141966/fast-and-scalable-rpc-between-c-sharp-and-cpython).

My question(s):

1. Is it possible to get zerorpc running with IronPython and if so, please could you give me a hint of how to do it?
2. If not, then are there any other equivalent packages that would provide the functionality in IronPython? There's a list here: [What is the current choice for doing RPC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python), but does anyone know if any of these work with IronPython?

---

**Update 2**
Following @PawelJasinski suggestion and his updates to pyzmq ironpython-backend, I have tried the following:

1. Installed IronPython 2.7.5b2 or later
2. Installed 32 bit version of zeromq from http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows
3. Clone `ironpython-backend` branch from  https://github.com/paweljasinski/pyzmq/tree/ironpython-backend
4. In `pyzmq` dir, run `ipy.exe setup.py install --user`
5. Clone zerorpc from https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python
6. In `zerorpc-python`, run `ipy.exe setup.py install --user`
7. Set the environment variable: `set PYZMQ_BACKEND=zmq.backend.ctypes`
8. Attempted to use the 'Cooler' class example from https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python, running with `ipy.exe -X:Frames cooler.py`

(cooler.py):

```
class Cooler(object):
    """ Various convenience methods to make things cooler. """

    def add_man(self, sentence):
        """ End a sentence with ", man!" to make it sound cooler, and
        return the result. """
        return sentence + ", man!"

    def add_42(self, n):
        """ Add 42 to an integer argument to make it cooler, and return the
        result. """
        return n + 42

    def boat(self, sentence):
        """ Replace a sentence with "I'm on a boat!", and return that,
        because it's cooler. """
        return "I'm on a boat!"

import zerorpc

s = zerorpc.Server(Cooler())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
s.run()
```

Now I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nlindop\AppData\Roaming\Python\IronPython27\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
  File "C:\Users\nlindop\AppData\Roaming\Python\IronPython27\site-packages\zmq\backend\ctypes\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nlindop\AppData\Roaming\Python\IronPython27\site-packages\zmq\backend\ctypes\constants.py", line 16, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ZMQ
```

Comment: You will need the same version of visual studio installed which was used to compile your version of python. Should be 2008, but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: @Puciek Thanks, I will check my setup and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

ZeroRPC appears to be pure python and is based on pyzmq. In this case you can try pyzmq `ctypes` backend for IronPython. https://github.com/paweljasinski/pyzmq/tree/ironpython-backend

- use IronPython 2.7.5b2 or newer
- install 32-bit version of zmq from http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows
- install pyzmq itself, clone, than `ipy.exe setup.py install --user`. Install should detect your zmq and pick the right dll
- activate the ctypes backend, set the environment variable `PYZMQ_BACKEND=zmq.backend.ctypes`

UPDATE: ZeroRPC has dependency on `gevent` which is not available under IronPython, so the above instructions are valid only for pyzmq under IronPython

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the question, but I think your answer is still relevant. I will give it a try. @PawelJasinski

Comment: I have updated my question with the log from my latest attempt. Looks like I need Visual Studio 6.

Comment: something makes setup believe it is cpython and not ironpython.

Comment: @CaptainWhippet please switch to iron-cleanup branch. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @CaptainWhippet the ironpython-backend branch should have a working setup.py now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64301/discussion-between-captain-whippet-and-pawel-jasinski).

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of the question. [pyro](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4) (and  its dependency [serpent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/serpent)) support IronPython and Jython.

Warning: stay away from IronPython 2.7.5b3 - it has a [bug](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/35667) which breaks serpent. 2.7.4 and 2.7.5b2 are ok. Next 2.7.5 has a fix.